# COM and Services

Tags: delphi, service, com, marshalling

I'm trying to create a service to communicate with a COM object that controls on BarCode Scanner (model Motorola Symbol LS9208).

I created the TLB unit from ocx installed with scanner driver application.

In Delphi, <del>I had create a DataModule that make all the work</del> I put the start and stop code of scanner in ServiceExecute procedure:

1. Initialize the TScanner COM object (declared in TLB)
2. Set some scanner properties, "claim" the control and set one TScanner event with one of the procedures in <del>DataModule</del> Service to fire when barcode is readed
3. After all, before close, release and free the TScanner object

   ```
   procedure TInteliPEDCheckService.ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
   begin

     debugLog( 'initialization of service thread...' );

     CheckInitParams;

     //DataModule_Create;

     startScanner;

     //loopback
     while (not Terminated) do
     begin
       Sleep(100);
       ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(False);
     end;

     debugLog( 'end of service loop...' ); //only reached if stop service before read codbar

     stopScanner;

     //DataModule_Free;

     debugLog( 'finalization of service thread...' );

   end;

   procedure TInteliPEDCheckService.startScanner;
   var HR : HRESULT;
   begin

     //CoInitialize( nil );
     //CoInitializeEx( nil, COINIT_MULTITHREADED );
     //CoInitializeEx( nil, COINIT_MULTITHREADED or COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE );
     //CoInitializeEx( nil, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED );
     CoInitializeEx( nil, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED or COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE );

     // I've tried all options above, but without success

     HR := CoInitializeSecurity(
       nil, -1, nil, nil,
       1, // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_NONE
       1, // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_ANONYMOUS
       nil,
       0, // EOAC_NONE
       nil);

     debugLog( 'HRESULT of CoInitializeSecurity: ' + IntToStr( HR ) );
     // the log always shows 0 as HRESULT

     Scanner := TScanner.Create( nil );

     Scanner.Open( 'STI_USBSCANNER' );

     if Scanner.Claim(0) = 0 then
     begin

       Scanner.OnDataEvent := ScannerDataEvent;
       //Scanner.OnDirectIOEvent := ScannerDirectIOEvent;

       Scanner.DeviceEnabled    := TRUE;
       Scanner.DataEventEnabled := TRUE;
       Scanner.FreezeEvents     := FALSE;

     end
     else
     begin
       Scanner.DeviceEnabled    := FALSE;
       Scanner.DataEventEnabled := FALSE;
       Scanner.FreezeEvents     := FALSE;
     end;

     //  Caption := IfThen( Scanner.Claimed, 'OK', 'FAIL' );

   end;

   procedure TInteliPEDCheckService.stopScanner;
   begin

     if ( Scanner <> nil ) then
     begin

       Scanner.Release;
       Scanner.Free;

       CoUninitialize();

     end;

   end;

   procedure TInteliPEDCheckService.ScannerDataEvent(ASender: TObject; lStatus: Integer);
   begin

     debugLog( 'will fire...' ); //never reached

     debugLog( 'FIRED: ' + Scanner.ScanData );

     //Scanner.DeviceEnabled    := FALSE;
     //Sleep(1000);
     Scanner.DeviceEnabled    := TRUE;
     Scanner.DataEventEnabled := TRUE;

   end;
   ```

When I <del>create the DataModule</del> run this code into an EXE application, everything works fine. But now I'm migrating this funcionality to a Windows Service.

As first problem, the error of "CoInitialize not called" fired and nothing works.

So, I tried to CoInitialize() in service's DPR, before Application.Initialize but don't solve, and error keep raising.

The error only gone when I put CoInitialize() just before TScanner.Create(nil), so the scanner starts and I could see the laser ready to read barcodes.

Now the scanner starts fine with the service start, and stop fine too when service stops.

But if I read some barcode, and the event OnDataEvent is about to be triggered, the service is halted, and no data is received, an (of course) I lost the control of the scanner, needing to restart the service.

I read some instructions of how to CoInitialize the COM objects (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485844(v=vs.85).aspx) and found some mention about marshalling technique to transport data between COM objects and other threads. But I'm not sure if this is the problem... and I don't know how to do that.

The service always halt when I scan some barcode. If not, starts and stops without errors, and the laser lights on when start, and light off when stop, demonstrating normal and correct command and operation.

Please, some one can help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: COM initialization is per thread. You have to initialize the thread on which your COM object runs. That explains the first issue. You probably want a single threaded apartment. As for the rest you need to do some debugging.

Comment: As david said, call your `startScanner` and `stopScanner` methods in the `Execute` method of your thread.

Comment: I tried, but the error keep occur. The debugging can show me nothing new... the OnDataEvent never called, or service halts when its called, but the code into is never reached. MULTITHREAD or APARTMENTTHREAD is same result

Comment: Run the service under debugger to see what happens when you scan.

Comment: You need to debug harder.

Comment: Gather more information. Strip out code until behaviour changes. It's hard for us to debug.

Comment: Now the code above is updated with last changes. I've tried with all CoInitialize options, with same result: halt when scan! Any more sugestions?

Comment: I suggest you debug your program

Answer (score 0):

I once solved COM trouble within an NT-service by calling [CoInitializeSecurity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693736(v=vs.85).aspx) right after CoInitialize. I wrote more about it [here](http://yoy.be/i282.html). Apart from that it is important to get the threading right. So be sure by debugging the 'normal' application version and using [GetCurrentThreadId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683183(v=vs.85).aspx) that the incoming data from the scanner is handled by the exact thread you expect it on.

Comment: In Application version, I called GetCurrentThreadId in startScanner procedure and get the same value when called into ScannerDataEvent procedure. Only for check, the value of GetCurrentProcessId was the same in both too! Now I'm trying to call CoInitializeSecurity right after CoInitialize, as you said, but I'm not sure about the correct parameters...